# How to optimize converting DataFrame to dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, pandas

I have a pd.DataFrame that I need converted to a dictionary. Here's an example DataFrame (call it mydf):

```
   user_id    colors
0  1000       red
1  1000       yellow
2  1000       blue
3  2000       yellow
4  2000       green
```

I would like the keys in the dictionary to be distinct user_id values (in this case 1000 and 2000). I need its values to be the subset of the DataFrame corresponding to its respective key. What's the fastest way to convert this into a dictionary so that when I call

```
mydict[1000]
```

it returns

```
   user_id    colors
0  1000       red
1  1000       yellow
2  1000       blue
```

?

I'm seeking an alternative to simply calling

```
mydf[mydf['user_id']==1000]
```

because my .csv is super large and I think this would optimize the lookup. Any other suggestions are appreciated!

My current solution is below, but I'm looking for alternatives because this takes about 40 minutes to build on a 1.1GB .csv.

```
mydict = {}

for idx, row in mydf.iterrows():
     if row['user_id'] not in mydict:
         mydict[row['user_id']] = [mydf.loc[idx]]
     else:
         mydict[row['user_id']].append(mydf.loc[idx])
```

Comment: why do you think `mydf[mydf['user_id']==1000]` is not fast enough already?

Comment: Last I looked, DataFrame indexing is slower than dict lookups.

Comment: For a 5,000,000 row df based on your data it takes `df[df['user_id']==1000]` 336ms and `df.loc[df['user_id']==1000]` 317ms, if you made 'user_id' your index then `df.loc[1000]` takes 447us

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
In [6]: {k: v.colors.tolist() for k, v in df.groupby('user_id')}
Out[6]: {1000: ['red', 'yellow', 'blue'], 2000: ['yellow', 'green']}
```

No performance guarantees though. `tolist` may be a bit slow.